# I want to start Durga Devi Sadhana

Tags: durga, shakti, sadhana

If there is anyone who is doing Durga Sadhana could you please share some info. Is there any mantra that needs to be recited daily?
I find reciting 32 names of Durga Devi stotram is one approach. but I am keen on knowing if there are any mantras to do Sadhana because mantras can be done anywhere and I personally feel it is easy for me to start.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: In Hinduism sadhana is done under a Guru and it starts with Diksha .. for uninitiates the best method is to do nama japa or Stotra recital. If you do this sncerely and with devotion for few days Goddess Durga will herself show you the next step .. you can recite Durga Stava Raja daily maintaining purity

Comment: Welcome to HSE! This looks like a personal advice question which is off topic here, hence your question shall be closed. To learn more, Feel free to take a [tour] of the site before getting started.

Comment: do you have the reference of durga 32 names? from which scripture?